# Bootstrap-glyphicons is not display when using with Angular-Translate

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-translate

I was surprised about the icon wasn't shown when I'm put the attribute translate in the button with glyphicons (no glyphicons is fine!!).

My index.html

```
<button id="CartButton" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CartModal" translate="HEAD.CART">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> ({{ROLineList.length}}) Cart
</button>
```

My app.js

```
app.config(function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('th', {
        HEAD: {
            CART: 'ตะกร้า'
        }
    });
    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        HEAD: {
            CART: 'Cart'
        }
    });
    $translateProvider.translations('cn', {
        HEAD: {
            CART: '大車'
        }
    });
});
```

It's OK for the menu, but the button not displaying bootstrap-glyphicons but also show wrong position of label as in the following image.
Right now, I have not enough reputations to post image, I draft you a layout the menu and the cart button like this

```
menu --> Product | Webboard | Payment | About us  [ (Cart) Cart ]  <---- button (EN)

menu --> สินค้า    | เว็บบอร์ด  |การชำระเงิน| เกี่ยวกับเรา  [ (ตะกร้า) Cart ] <---- button (TH)
```

I hope it can display bootstrap-glyphicons and the label is shown in appropriate position something like

```
[ icon (0) ตะกร้า ] or [ icon (0) Cart ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the directive `translate="HEAD.CART"` from angular-translate replaces the innerHTML of the element that is being applied to, thus you lose the `<span class="glyphicon"></span>`  inside the `button`.

A workaround is to use another `span` as translate directive on a inner element, inside of the wrapping element. For instance:

```
<button id="CartButton" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CartModal">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> 
    ({{ROLineList.length}}) <span translate="HEAD.CART"></span>
</button>
```

This approach has a better performance than using the filter, because it doesn't set any additional watchers (see the [docs](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/05_using-translate-directive)).

You might also consider using [variable replacement](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/06_variable-replacement) when you have inline values.

Answer (score 0):

Update!! I've changed from using attribute

> translate="HEAD.CART"

in  to use {{'HEAD.CART' | translate}} instead.

my old code snippet:

```
<button id="CartButton" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CartModal" translate="HEAD.CART">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> ({{ROLineList.length}}) Cart
</button>
```

My new code snippet:

```
<button id="CartButton" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CartModal" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> ({{ROLineList.length}}) {{'HEAD.CART'| translate}}
    </button>
```

Finally, It works great right now.

Thanks.